# wal-g restore error - Failed to fetch backup: failed to fetch sentinel: context canceled

Tags: postgresql, database-backups, database-restore

I am using zolando postgres-operator to setup back up and restore in Kubernetes cluster. The backups are done using `wal-g` and uploaded into gcp bucket. The backups are running fine

```
wal-g backup-list
name                          last_modified        wal_segment_backup_start
base_000000020000000000000007 2019-12-19T03:56:22Z 000000020000000000000007
base_00000003000000000000000A 2019-12-19T04:34:41Z 00000003000000000000000A
base_000000010000000000000003 2019-12-19T04:40:01Z 000000010000000000000003
```

However when I try to restore, I get the below error

```
wal-g backup-fetch /home/postgres/pgdata/pgroot/data LATEST
INFO: 2019/12/19 10:06:24.765611 LATEST backup is: 'base_000000010000000000000003'
ERROR: 2019/12/19 10:06:25.062066 Failed to fetch backup: failed to fetch sentinel: context canceled
```

- Patroni 1.6.0
- Postgres 11
- wal-g 0.2.11

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was an error in wal-g version 0.2.11. This is fixed in 0.2.14